# scipy.interpolate.lagrange fails on some data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy

I just picked up python to implement machine learning assignments in order to practice the knowledge I gathered in class.

I'm new to python, therefore I just discovered [spicy](https://docs.scipy.org) library that offers a bunch of very useful mathematical tools among them Lagrange interpolation for 1D polynomials using `interpolate.lagrange`.

I'm trying to use that function to have an equation that I'll use afterwards. Although I'm getting the following error:

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py:1186:
>   RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide   return
>   poly1d(self.coeffs/other)
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py:681:
>   RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

---

Code:

```
import sys
import math
import os
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []
file = open(os.getcwd()+"/practice/train.txt", "r")
for line in file.read().split():
     x.append(float(line.split(',')[0])) 
     y.append(float(line.split(',')[1]))


poly = interpolate.lagrange(x, y)
print poly(1.5)
```

---

Training dataset: https://s3.amazonaws.com/hr-testcases/399/assets/trainingdata.txt

---

What I have tried so far: I understood that some lines in data result into the zero division. Using divide and conquer on the dataset; erasing some lines would make it work but I'll lose accuracy in a way that `poly(x)` print a non accurate y (f(x)).

Note: I still have not tracked the line triggering the zero division.

Any explanation would very appreciated.

Comment: The data that you present is not ordered and the result looks like a piecewise linear function, that is not ideally interpolated using polynomials.
Also, the lagrange interpolating routine mentions "Warning: This implementation is numerically unstable. Do not expect to be able to use more than about 20 points even if they are chosen optimally.". Could you mention why you chose that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the divide by zero error is that you have duplicate data points. For example, `x[40]` and `x[64]` are the same. Because of how the algorithm works, at some point you'll end up doing `something / (x[40] - x[64])`.

However, even if you remove duplicates, you have other problems. Your dataset represents the function `f(x) = 2 * x if x < 4 else 8`. This is not a trivial polynomial and the interpolation will fail wildly in its attempt. Furthermore, your data points are shuffled, which means you should expect different results depending on what slice of your dataset you take, e.g., only points for `x > 4`, or only `x < 4`, or most likely, something in the between.

Last, but not least important, even if you sort your data points in an ascending order, the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.lagrange.html) for the function states it's numerically unstable.

> Warning: This implementation is numerically unstable. Do not expect to be able to use more than about 20 points even if they are chosen optimally.

```
>>> xx, yy = list(zip(*sorted(set(zip(x, y)))))
>>> for k in range(15, 25):
    print(k, interpolate.lagrange(xx[:k], yy[:k])(1))


15 1.99999915221
16 1.99998531246
17 1.99992345466
18 1.99993904792
19 2.00236333472
20 2.01589034207
21 -1.04477498867
22 -20.8148132927
23 -172.983956978
24 4185.90603781
```

Comment: Using naked eye I could as well conclude that for every x>4 y=8. Do you believe that taking all x<4 and interpolating the polynomial would give something I can work with?

Comment: Before your answered me I visualized the data on R. Using paper and pen I could figure out that my f(x) can take 2x when x<4 and 8 when x>4 as mentioned. Although, Lagrange kept failing due to what you just said. Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Comment: I'll be looking forward sir.